# Auto Source to Target Column Mapping for Views - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to map column sources to the alias given to the column in views. We have quite a few views and I want to dynamically map the column names in those views to their respective, I always wanted a proc I can run that will basically tell me where the views columns get their data from, think of it as auto documentation. I have opted to do this by using the execution path. I extract the execution path XML and then retrieve the column names/aliases from the execution path and then trace the column sources via the execution path XML.

This might get a bit confusing so let me put down what I have done so far:

1. Execute a simple select statement into a temp table - this will allow for the column names to appear in the execution path and will also register the execution path in the sys.dm_exec_cached_plans table
2. Retrieve the execution path XML into @XML
3. Retrieve the column names and then store them into a variable table
4. Retrieve the different nodes for each expression and each union and sore that in a new variable table
5. Extract the column names from the union/expression nodes - This is done via loop through the list gotten in point 4
6. Extract the Target column data, this includes database, table, and then a parent and child column entry to handle the relationships as they are available in the execution path. I also include the Scalar String because it may contain useful transformation information for each column.
7. Create the initial relationships for each entity identified in point 6
8. Loop through the entities (this is where things are starting to go wrong I imagine), this loop is supposed to identify relationships and then move the target column closer and closer to the most top layer parent available for the node (meaning tie the column and its meta data in to the top most parent node identifier be it ExprXXXX or UnionXXXX) Note: I do this loop 5 times, but I initially was thinking of doing the loop until no more unidentified relationships exists, hence the flag.
9. Join the results to my columns and my expressions to the columns, resulting in a list of all view column names, and their source information.

Here is the code so far:

```
DECLARE @view_name varchar(100)=  'v_viewX', @schema varchar(100) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @view sysname
SET @view = upper(concat(@schema, '.', @view_name))

DECLARE @SelectStatement varchar(250)= 'SELECT TOP 10 * INTO #T_TESTEXECUTION FROM ' + @view

EXEC (@SelectStatement)

DECLARE @XML AS XML

SELECT TOP 1 @XML = EX_QP.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans EX_CP
JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats EX_STAT ON EX_STAT.plan_handle = EX_CP.plan_handle
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(EX_CP.plan_handle) EX_QP
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(EX_CP.plan_handle) EX_SQLTXT
WHERE EX_SQLTXT.TEXT = @SelectStatement
ORDER BY EX_STAT.last_execution_time

DECLARE @ColumnAliases TABLE (ExecutionAlias VARCHAR(100), ColumnAlias VARCHAR(100))
--Retrive the column mappings
;WITH xmlnamespaces (default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
INSERT INTO @ColumnAliases
SELECT 
    [ExecutionAlias]   = x.value('(@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)'),
    [ColumnAlias]   = x1.x.value('(../../../ColumnReference/@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)')
    --[Table]   = x1.x.value('(../../../ColumnReference/@Table)[1]',   'varchar(8000)')
    --,X = x.query('/.')
    --ScalarString   = x.value('(//@ScalarString)[1]',   'varchar(8000)')
FROM   @XML.nodes('//ColumnReference') x1(x)
WHERE x1.x.value('(../../../ColumnReference/@Table)[1]',   'varchar(8000)') = '[#T_TESTEXECUTION]'

DECLARE @Nodes TABLE (Node xml, ID int identity)
--retreive the Unions and their expressions
;WITH xmlnamespaces (default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
INSERT INTO @Nodes
SELECT 
    X = x.query('..')
FROM   @XML.nodes('//DefinedValue/ColumnReference') x1(x)
WHERE x.value('(@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)') LIKE 'Union%' OR x.value('(@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)') LIKE 'EXPR[0-9][0-9]%'

DECLARE @ExpressionRelation TABLE (UnionName varchar(100), ExpressionValue varchar(100))
DECLARE @cnt int
DECLARE @XMLNode XML

--select * from @Nodes

SET @cnt = (select count(1) from @Nodes)
WHILE @cnt > 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Union varchar(100)

    SELECT @XMLNode = node
    FROM @Nodes
    WHERE ID = @cnt

;WITH xmlnamespaces (default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
    SELECT 
        @Union   = x.value('(@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)')
    FROM   @XMLNode.nodes('//ColumnReference') x1(x)
    WHERE x.value('(@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)') LIKE 'Union%' OR x.value('(@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)') LIKE 'EXPR[0-9][0-9]%'

;WITH xmlnamespaces (default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
    INSERT INTO @ExpressionRelation (UnionName, ExpressionValue)
    SELECT @Union, x.value('(@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)')
    FROM  @XMLNode.nodes('//ColumnReference') x1(x)
    WHERE x.value('(@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)') NOT LIKE 'Union%' OR x.value('(@Column)[1]',   'varchar(8000)') LIKE 'EXPR[0-9][0-9]%'
    
SET @cnt = @cnt - 1;
END

DECLARE @Relationships TABLE 
(
    [ParentColumn]  varchar(max),
    [ChildColumn]   varchar(max),
    [Database]      varchar(max),
    [Schema]        varchar(max),
    [Table]         varchar(max),
    [Alias]         varchar(max),
    [ScalarString]  varchar(max)
)

DECLARE @RelationshipsFinal TABLE 
(
    [ParentColumn]  varchar(max),
    [ChildColumn]   varchar(max),
    [Database]      varchar(max),
    [Schema]        varchar(max),
    [Table]         varchar(max),
    [Alias]         varchar(max),
    [ScalarString]  varchar(max)
)

;WITH xmlnamespaces (default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
    INSERT INTO @Relationships
    SELECT 
         [ParentColumn]  = x.value('(..//@Column)[1]',   'varchar(MAX)'),
         [ChildColumn]   = x.value('(..//Identifier/ColumnReference/@Column)[1]',   'varchar(MAX)'),
         [Database]      = x.value('(..//@Database)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') ,
         [Schema]        = x.value('(..//@Schema)[1]',   'varchar(MAX)') ,
         [Table]         = x.value('(..//@Table)[1]',    'varchar(MAX)') ,
         [Alias]         = x.value('(..//@Alias)[1]',    'varchar(MAX)') ,
         [ScalarString]  = x.value('(..//@ScalarString)[1]',   'varchar(MAX)')
    FROM   @XML.nodes('//DefinedValue/ColumnReference') x1(x)

DELETE FROM @Relationships WHERE ParentColumn LIKE 'UNION%' AND ChildColumn IS NULL

UPDATE T1
SET
    T1.ScalarString =  REPLACE(T1.ScalarString, T2.ParentColumn, T2.ScalarString)
FROM @Relationships T1
    INNER JOIN @Relationships T2 on T1.ScalarString LIKE CONCAT('%' , T2.ParentColumn , '%')
    AND T2.ParentColumn = T1.ChildColumn
    AND T2.ParentColumn LIKE 'EXPR%'
    AND T1.ScalarString != T2.ScalarString

DECLARE @RelationshipsTemp TABLE 
    (
    [ParentColumn]  varchar(max),
    [ChildColumn]   varchar(max),
    [Database]      varchar(max),
    [Schema]        varchar(max),
    [Table]         varchar(max),
    [Alias]         varchar(max),
    [ScalarString]  varchar(max)
    )

    ;WITH CTE_Children AS(
        SELECT * FROM 
        @Relationships r1 
        WHERE ChildColumn is null 
        )
    INSERT INTO @RelationshipsTemp
    select DISTINCT
        R.[ParentColumn]
        ,CASE WHEN C.[ChildColumn]      IS NOT NULL THEN C.[ChildColumn]   ELSE R.[ChildColumn]  END AS [ChildColumn]   
        ,CASE WHEN C.[Database]     IS NOT NULL THEN C.[Database]      ELSE R.[Database]     END AS [Database]   
        ,CASE WHEN C.[Schema]       IS NOT NULL THEN C.[Schema]        ELSE R.[Schema]       END AS [Schema]         
        ,CASE WHEN C.[Table]            IS NOT NULL THEN C.[Table]         ELSE R.[Table]        END AS [Table]      
        ,CASE WHEN C.[Alias]            IS NOT NULL THEN C.[Alias]         ELSE R.[Alias]        END AS [Alias]         
        ,CASE WHEN R.[ScalarString] IS NOT NULL THEN R.[ScalarString]  ELSE C.[ScalarString] END AS [ScalarString]  
    from 
    @Relationships r 
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Children c
    on r.ChildColumn = c.ParentColumn

    INSERT INTO @RelationshipsFinal
    SELECT * FROM @RelationshipsTemp

DECLARE @flag BIT = 1;
DECLARE @COUNTLOOP INT  = 0

--loop to tie in nodes to root nodes
WHILE (  @COUNTLOOP  < 5)
BEGIN
    
    DELETE FROM @RelationshipsTemp

    INSERT INTO @RelationshipsTemp
    select DISTINCT
        R.[ParentColumn]
        ,CASE WHEN C.[ChildColumn]      IS NOT NULL THEN C.[ChildColumn]   ELSE R.[ChildColumn]  END AS [ChildColumn]   
        ,CASE WHEN C.[Database]     IS NOT NULL THEN C.[Database]      ELSE R.[Database]     END AS [Database]   
        ,CASE WHEN C.[Schema]       IS NOT NULL THEN C.[Schema]        ELSE R.[Schema]       END AS [Schema]         
        ,CASE WHEN C.[Table]            IS NOT NULL THEN C.[Table]         ELSE R.[Table]        END AS [Table]      
        ,CASE WHEN C.[Alias]            IS NOT NULL THEN C.[Alias]         ELSE R.[Alias]        END AS [Alias]         
        ,CASE WHEN R.[ScalarString] IS NOT NULL THEN R.[ScalarString]  ELSE C.[ScalarString] END AS [ScalarString]  
    from 
    @RelationshipsFinal r 
    LEFT JOIN @RelationshipsFinal c on r.ChildColumn = c.ParentColumn 
    
    DELETE FROM @RelationshipsFinal

    INSERT INTO @RelationshipsFinal
    SELECT * FROM @RelationshipsTemp
    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @RelationshipsFinal WHERE ParentColumn NOT IN (SELECT ExpressionValue FROM @ExpressionRelation))
        SET @flag = 1
    ELSE 
        SET @flag = 0

    SET @COUNTLOOP = @COUNTLOOP +1
END

DELETE FROM @RelationshipsFinal WHERE ParentColumn = ChildColumn

SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.ColumnAlias
    ,CASE WHEN R.ParentColumn LIKE 'EXPR[0-9][0-9]%' THEN R.[ChildColumn] ELSE R.ParentColumn END AS [SourceColumn]
    ,R.[Database]   AS [SourceDatabase]     
    ,R.[Schema]     AS [SourceSchema]   
    ,R.[Table]      AS [SourceTable]    
    ,R.[Alias]      AS [SourceAlias]    
    ,R.[ScalarString]
FROM @ColumnAliases A 
INNER JOIN @ExpressionRelation E on A.ExecutionAlias = E.UnionName
JOIN @RelationshipsFinal R ON E.ExpressionValue = R.ParentColumn
```

There are many things wrong with this code, it is un-optimized and not very pretty, but so far it gets the job done for a few views I have tested it on. The problem is that it is not behaving properly for more complex views. It gets quite volatile especially with more complex views. I think with a bit of work, this can be something very useful, but I am starting to worry that it might not be possible because of the dynamic nature of the execution paths.

I want to get the basic functionality working before optimizing it.

I guess the questions here is:

- Am I using the correct nodes? Or should I be doing it in another way?
- Is it even possible to do this via the execution path XML?
- Is there perhaps a better, more elegant way to link the lowest child node, to the top most parent node?

*Please note that you should be able to run this query for any view, so feel free to test it out, but only use it on smaller / simpler views for now as it does take a considerable amount of time to execute for more complex views.*

Any comments, critiques or hints welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ..your goal is to map a view column to a table column for all applicable cases? eg. viewX selects from viewY which in turn selects from tableZ..the goal is to map viewX.columnA to tableZ.columnB?